# Unit testing DelegateCommand using Rhino Mock

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, mvvm, rhino-mocks

I am trying to unit test a command execution for a command that displays a dialog, however I keep getting NullReferenceException and I do not know why. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

The viewmodel being used by view snippet:

```
public class ConvertFileDialogViewModel:IConvertFileDialogViewModel
{
    private string _inputFolderPath;

    public DelegateCommand SelectInputFolderCommand { get;set; }
        
    public ConvertFileDialogViewModel()
    {
        SelectInputFolderCommand = new DelegateCommand(SelectInputFolderDialog);
    }

    public string InputFolderPath
    {
        get => _inputFolderPath;
        set
        {
            _inputFolderPath = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(InputFolderPath));
        }
    }
        

    public void SelectInputFolderDialog()
    {
        using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
            {
                InputFolderPath = fbd.SelectedPath;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Interface snippet:

```
public interface IConvertInterviewDialogViewModel
{
    string InputFolderPath { get; set; }
    DelegateCommand SelectInputFolderCommand { get;set; }
    
}
```

Unit-Test snippet:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SelectInputFolderCommandTest()
{
    var model = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IConvertFileDialogViewModel>();
    model.SelectInputFolderCommand.Execute();
    model.AssertWasCalled(vm=>vm.SelectInputFolderCommand);
}
```

Error:

`ConvertInterviewDialogViewModelTests.SelectInputFolderCommandTest threw exception:  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Answer (score 1):

I have never used Rhino Mocks, but what I can infer from

```cs
var model = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IConvertFileDialogViewModel>();
```

is that you create a mock of an interface, that will not call the constructor of `ConvertFileDialogViewModel`, thus the `SelectInputFolderCommand` property will remain `null`.

**Edit**:
As Nkosi correctly pointed out, you can't use the command of your ViewModel, as it would invoke a dialog, which you can't unit test.
Thus, you need to initialize the `SelectInputFolderCommand` property after creating the mock.

Comment: Your observation is correct, but your suggestion about mocking the subject under test is wrong in this case. Their code is tightly coupled to UI concerns that make testing it in isolation difficult with out refactoring the tight coupling.

Comment: @Nkosi: Oh, you are right, the command would call a dialog, which isn't great for unit testing.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I decoupled the UI component and tested the bit that returned the path.